# Is it ok to use voltage dividers instead of voltage regulators when adjusting reference voltages for opAmps?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-reference

My question is about manually adjustable circuits with a knob, coarse ect. When adjusting reference voltage of an opamp, for instance, trigger level of a schmitt trigger or gain of an amplifier manually, can we just use a potentiometer(or voltage divider)?

Comment: It's normal to use potentiometers or voltage dividers, however the accuracy and stability can only be as good as the source from which you are dividing. Sometimes power supplies can be used as references, but often they're too inaccurate, too unstable and too noisy to be used directly. You have to do the math.

Comment: I've used the power rails as references... figuring I was going to adjust it so the exact value didn't matter.  And then regretted the power supply noise that followed.  So put some holes/pads on your layout for the inevitable capacitor to ground.  (a few $ for a reference or $/2 for a regulator is not much.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use voltage dividers for setting reference voltages.  There are a few questions that you need to answer, though.

1) How accurate does the reference need to be?  Will the temperature coefficient of the voltage divider components have any effect?

2) What feeds the voltage divider?  Does *that* have sufficient accuracy and stability?

In general, what you are asking is generally considered to be standard practice.  The reason this is the case is that many times, the reference voltage that you need either needs to be variable (to allow for calibration / setup) or the voltage that you need as the reference is not available as a standard part.

Comment: batteries feed the circuit not a power suppply. does that matter in this case?

Comment: How stable are the batteries?  Depending on the circuit, this can not only be a valid question, but a very important one.  All batteries have internal resistance so that a heavy load will reduce their voltage.  And a spiky load can give you a spiky voltage directly from the battery.